# Equivalent to accessors in Ada

Tags: ada, accessor

Is there a way to create an equivalent to C# get/set in Ada ?

I have a type like this (in Ada) :

```
-- Ada :
type MyType is record 
    Value : Integer;
end record;
```

I want to split the value like this

```
-- Ada :
type MyType is record 
    ten  : Integer;
    unit : Integer;
end record;
```

But I want to keep `MyType.Value` (referenced in many readonly files). I want to create an accessor but I did not find how to do in Ada. I know how to do in C# :

```
// C# :
int Value
{
    get
    {
        return this.ten * 10 + this.unit;
    }
    set
    {
        this.unit = value % 10;
        this.ten = value / 10;
    }
}
```

What I want to do :

```
-- ada :
MyType var := MyType'(Value => 15); -- unmodified code
var.Value := 65; -- can be modified like before

Integer ten := var.ten; -- new getter
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in the comment of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59199588/347964) to your previous question, There's no language construct that does it for you. Depending on your use-case, you could possibly employ controlled types:

```
type MyTypeView (Data : not null access MyType) is limited
  new Ada.Finalization.Limited_Controlled with record
   Value: Integer;
end record;

overriding procedure Initialize (Object : in out MyTypeView) is
begin
   Object.Value := Object.Data.ten * 10 + Object.Data.unit;
end Initialize;

overriding procedure Finalize (Object : in out MyTypeView) is
begin
   Object.Data.ten := Object.Value / 10;
   Object.Data.unit := Object.Value mod 10;
end Finalize;
```

This would allow you to alter the Value in the way you want with the View:

```
declare
   --  assuming MyObj is an object of type MyType
   View : MyTypeView (MyObj'Access);
   --  Initialize will be called, setting View.Value
begin
   --  can access value as "property"
   Do_Something (View.Value);
   --  can assign value as "property"
   View.Value := 123;
   --  when View goes out of scope, Finalize will be called, updating MyObj
end;
```

Note however that as long as View lives, View.Value is detached from the original object, meaning that at the `end;`, other modifications of MyObj that happened after View has been created will be discarded. In a single-threaded program, this means that you may not call any subroutines that may instantiate a View of the same object while the current view lives (and may not directly instantiate a second View of this object inside the block).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your previous answer unlocked me but it's a new problem. I edited my question to be more clear (hope it's better, i'm new to ada)

Comment: As I said, there is no language feature supporting directly what you want. You can always go the way of having a `function My_Value() return V_Type` and a `procedure Set_My_Value (Value : V_Type)` but there is no special property syntax as in C#.

Comment: I tried your solution, it seems to work but I have an error "unconstrained element type in array declaration" when I do `type MyTypeArray is array (MyRange) of MyTypeView`

Comment: You can't use `MyTypeView` in an array since it has a discriminant. Giving values to the discriminant constrains the type, and an array requires constrained inner types. You can't have an array with types having different discriminants.

Answer (score 7):

This is a job for a private type.

```
package Hidden is
   type T is tagged private;

   function New_T (Value : Integer) return T;

   function Value (Tee : T) return Integer;
   function Ten   (Tee : T) return Integer;
   function Unit  (Tee : T) return Integer;
private -- Hidden
   type T is tagged record
      Ten  : Integer;
      Unit : Integer;
   end record;
   ...
end Hidden;
```

Now you can write things like

```
V : T := New_T (42);
...
Put_Line (Item => V.Value'Image & V.Ten'Image & V.Unit'Image);
V := New_T (23);
```